# Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup

Tags: view, runtimeexception, viewgroup

I'm trying an exercise to list an get the sensors info, but I'm getting the titles error, and i have no much info about it, could somebody help me?

The exercise says:

"This activity uses the layout created from XML, which basically is an empty linearlayout. From Java we access to this layout with the object "raiz". To the layout we will be adding a series of views according to the sensors found in the device. For each sensor is added: a TextView with the name of the sensor; a LinearLayout of horizontal type to contain: a TextView with "X" and the sensor value on this axis; a TextView with the value of the sensor in "Y"; a TextView with the value of teh axis "Z", if applies. The references to the TextView where the values ​​of the sensors are displayed are stored in aTextView [] [] array, where the first index identifies the sensor number and the second the dimension, X, Y, Z.

The `onSensorChanged()` method makes a loop to locate the sensor index that has changed and the TextViews corresponding to the sensor are modified with the values ​​read"

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/raiz"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity main

```
    package com.example.familia.sensores2;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private List<Sensor> listaSensores;
private TextView aTextView[][] = new TextView[20][3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout raiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.raiz);
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    listaSensores = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    int n = 0;
    for(Sensor sensor:listaSensores){
        TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
        mTextView.setText(sensor.getName());
        raiz.addView(mTextView);
        LinearLayout nLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        raiz.addView(nLinearLayout);
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
            aTextView[n][i] = new TextView(this);
            aTextView[n][i].setText("?");
            aTextView[n][i].setWidth(87);
        }
        TextView xTextView = new TextView(this);
        xTextView.setText(" X: ");
        nLinearLayout.addView(xTextView);
        nLinearLayout.addView(aTextView[n][0]);
        TextView yTextView = new TextView(this);
        yTextView.setText(" Y: ");
        nLinearLayout.addView(yTextView);
        nLinearLayout.addView(aTextView[n][1]);
        TextView zTextView = new TextView(this);
        zTextView.setText(" Z: ");
        nLinearLayout.addView(zTextView);
        nLinearLayout.addView(aTextView[n][2]);
        sm.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        n++;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    synchronized (this){
        int n = 0;
        for(Sensor sensor: listaSensores){
            if(event.sensor==sensor){
                for(int i=0; i<event.values.length; i++){
                    aTextView[n][i].setText(Float.toString(event.values[i]));
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
}}
```

here my error log

```
    06-05 03:10:17.523 17031-17031/com.example.familia.sensores2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.familia.sensores2, PID: 17031
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.familia.sensores2/com.example.familia.sensores2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4681)
    at com.example.familia.sensores2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here the full exercise code

[Master Android](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/recursos/36-unidad-5-entradas-en-android-teclado-pantalla-tactil-y-sensores/275-un-programa-que-muestra-los-sensores-disponibles-y-sus-valores-en-tiempo-real)

Answer (score 1):

well after a while looking and reading a lot, i found the error, or errors...

first on the lines:

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
            aTextView[n][i] = new TextView(this);
            aTextView[n][i].setText("?");
            aTextView[n][i].setWidth(87);
        }
```

i used the value "i<2" when on the exercise says "i<3" this because when i made the exercise for the first time i was getting an error for an "index out of bounds", so i thought that the error was on this line so i changed de value of "3" to "2" and was when i started to get the error of the post (Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup).

anyway, that error was because on the lines:

```
TextView zTextView = new TextView(this);
        zTextView.setText(" Z: ");
        nLinearLayout.addView(zTextView);
        nLinearLayout.addView(aTextView[n][2]);
```

the line:

```
nLinearLayout.addView(aTextView[n][2]);
```

was sending a null value and that caused the error of "Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup".

then when i returned the value to "3" i was getting the error of "index out of bounds", so i focused on the next lines:

```
        for(Sensor sensor: listaSensores){
            if(event.sensor==sensor){
                for(int i = 0; i <event.values.length; i++){
                    aTextView[n][i].setText(Float.toString(event.values[i]));
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
```

and the error was because the matrix defined on aTextView was for 20x3 but the "event.values.length" returned values greater than 3, why?, i don’t know... I’m not sure if it depends on the sensor type or what, so i added a restriction there and adjusted the lines to:

```
        for(Sensor sensor: listaSensores){
            if(event.sensor==sensor){
                for(int i = 0; i <event.values.length && i <3 ; i++){
                    aTextView[n][i].setText(Float.toString(event.values[i]));
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
```

and voila... the program runs.... finally i adjusted the activity main layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/raiz"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this because on my mobile i got a lot of sensors and i can’t view all, so i added a ScrollView.

now with the program running the values changes very fast and it’s impossible to read it, no matter if i modifies the value of "SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI" to, "SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL" or other... so I’m looking now how to make these changes slower, but the topic of this post can be closed, i hope this help others....